# How can I reset state machine to sub state machine?

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

Can you help me with this please?

I have states for employee `{ Start, S1 , S1_1_start, S1_1_end , S1_2_start, S1_2_end, S2, End }`.

```
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<EmployeeStates, EmployeeEvents> states) throws Exception {
     states
     .withStates()
         .initial(EmployeeStates.Start)
         .fork(EmployeeStates.FORK)
         .state(EmployeeStates.S1)
         .join(EmployeeStates.JOIN)
         .state(EmployeeStates.S2)
         .end(EmployeeStates.End)
     .and()
     .withStates()
         .parent(EmployeeStates.S1)
         .initial(EmployeeStates.S1_1_start)
         .end(EmployeeStates.S1_1_end)
     .and()
     .withStates()
         .parent(EmployeeStates.S1)
         .initial(EmployeeStates.S1_2_start)
         .end(EmployeeStates.S1_2_end);
}
```

I need to reset the machine state to start from `[S1, , S1_1_start, S1_2_end]` and add my event to reach to S2

Is this the correct way to reset my machine ?

```
StateMachine<EmployeeStates, EmployeeEvents> sm = this.factory.getStateMachine();
sm.stopReactively().subscribe();
sm.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(sma -> {
    sma.addStateMachineInterceptor(employeeStateChangeInterceptor);
    StateMachineContext<EmployeeStates,EmployeeEvents> ctx1 = new DefaultStateMachineContext(EmployeeStates.S1_1_start,null,null,null,null);
    StateMachineContext<EmployeeStates,EmployeeEvents> ctx2 = new DefaultStateMachineContext(EmployeeStates.S1_2_end,null,null,null,null);
    List<StateMachineContext<EmployeeStates,EmployeeEvents>> list = List.of(ctx1,ctx2);
    sma.resetStateMachineReactively(new DefaultStateMachineContext<EmployeeStates, EmployeeEvents>(list,EmployeeStates.S1, null,null, null,null)).subscribe();
});
```

In the log I see it is wrong, it changes the states to the expected state first, but then it does it again for the sub state :(

```
state changed from [S1, , S1_1_start ,S1_2_end ]  to ObjectState [S2]
state changed from [ S1_1_start ]  to ObjectState [S1_1_end]
```

Comment: Just a tip... Many people here who can help with your question are professionals.  "Can u" and "Wanna" are not professional expressions. They hurt your chances of receiving an answer. Perhaps English isn't your main language. If so, imperfect word choice is understandable. But it's still worth learning correct forms.

Comment: sorry excuse my broken English, It is not my home language

Comment: No apology needed. I couldn't post as well as you did in any language other than English.  As I said, it's just a tip...

Comment: I know only what I've read in the last 15 minutes about Spring state machines, so this is a guess.  It looks like your logic is applying _both_ contexts you've set up to _each_ region.  You may want to try adding names to the regions (with the `.region()` method). Then use these to determine which context to apply in each case. In any case, the builder API is not the best, and the documents are unclear. I hope you get an answer.

Comment: any answer on this?

Answer (score -1):

This is how I rehydrate (restore) a state machine out of some data in the non-reactive way

```
public static StateMachine restoreMachine(
      final StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine,
      final States currentState,
      final ExtendedState extendedState) {
    stateMachine
        .getStateMachineAccessor()
        .doWithAllRegions(
            sma ->
                sma.resetStateMachine(
                    new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(
                        currentState,
                        Events.E1,
                        null,
                        extendedState,
                        null,
                        "1")));
    return stateMachine;
  }
```

In which state do you expect to restore the machine at? My guess is that restoring a composite state could be different.. Also noticed you setting the interceptor every time you restore a machine? Maybe thats unnecessary

Comment: The question is how to restore child (forked) states. This answer only restores the top level state, but not forked states (S1_1_start ,S1_2_end)